# WPF BoolToBrushConverter with 4 values and 4 Brushes to return?

Tags: wpf, ivalueconverter, brush

I bind a TextBox`s Brush Property to an IsValid Dependency Property in a UserControl with a BoolToBrushConverter. My IsValid would need 4 states because I need 4 different brushes to return from the converter. Is there another way using strings? instead of bool, could that work?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You can convert whatever you want to whatever you want. You just need to implement the way *how* it is converted.

However, if the number of states is limited to 4, I would suggest using an *Enum* instead of strings because this makes it safer regarding refactoring etc.

Something like that should work:

```
internal enum State
{
    State1, State2, State3, State4
}

// ...

public void Convert(object value, ...)
{
    if (value is State)
    {
        State state = (State)value;
        switch(state)
        {
            case State.State1:
                return myBrush1;
            case State.State2:
                return myBrush2;
            case State.State3:
                return myBrush3;
            case State.State4:
                return myBrush4;
        }
    }

    return defaultBrush;
}
```

BTW: Depending on the scenario, it might be better to use triggers, but that is not always possible.